# Use ASP page from web application in SharePoint

Tags: asp.net, aspx, layouts

I'm trying to use existing aspx page in SharePoint 2010. Page it self depend on some 3rd party classes and I provided source for them and additional assemblies, and project compiles and deploys to sharepoint correctly.

Page is put in layouts directory. Page definition has also a Page directive:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Frameset.aspx.cs" Inherits="Frameset.Test.Source.Frameset.Frameset_Frameset"  %>
```

File `Frameset.aspx.cs` is present and project compiles without error. But when I try to access that page, I'm getting following error:

```
System.Web.HttpException: The file '/_layouts/Frameset.Test/Frameset/Frameset.aspx.cs' does not exist.
```

When I change `CodeFile` to `CodeBehind`, I'm getting following error:

```
System.Web.HttpException: Could not load type 'Frameset.Test.Source.Frameset.Frameset_Frameset'.
```

Which is strange, because this type (class) is defined in Frameset.aspx.cs, and VS doesn't complain about missing types.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, code-behind usage in SharePoint requires you to specify the full assembly name of the assembly that contains the codebehind class (that is - assuming that your assembly is deployed to the gac). Please see if by using the full name your problem is resolved, ie:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Frameset.aspx.cs" 
   Inherits="Frameset.Test.Source.Frameset.Frameset_Frameset, ........, Version=#.#.#.#, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=##########"  %>
```